# Code First Model Works on One PC, but Fails on Another

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

### Background

Code first model using ef4.1. Database is Oracle so we're using Devart dotConnect as well.

### Issue

After deploying the app to a server, saw errors with sql statements and invalid column names. Everything worked fine on my dev PC.

Created a small test console app and replicated the behavior. On my pc, not debugging but just running the app, it works fine and selects data correctly. On the server, the select statement has two extra column names for foreign keys.

### Entity

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server;
using log4net;

namespace Cul2.Model
{
    [Table("LAB_REQUISITION")]
    public class LabRequisition : EntityBase
    {
        public LabRequisition()
        {
            Attributes = new Collection<LabRequisitionAttribute>();
            Samples = new Collection<LabSample>();
        }

        [Key]
        [Column("REQUISITION_ID")]
        public long? RequisitionId { get; set; }

        [Column("MATERIAL_ID")]
        public long? MaterialId { get; set; }

        [Include]
        [Association("Material", "MaterialId", "MaterialId", IsForeignKey = true)]
        public virtual LabMaterial Material { get; set; }

        [Column("LAB_NUMBER")]
        public int? LabNumber { get; set; }

        [Column("COLLECTOR_ID")]
        public long? CollectorId { get; set; }

        [Include]
        [Association("Collector", "CollectorId", "UserId")]
        [ForeignKey("CollectorId")]
        public virtual ComUser Collector { get; set; }

        [Column("RECEIVER_ID")]
        public long? ReceiverId { get; set; }

        [Include]
        [Association("Receiver", "ReceiverId", "UserId")]
        [ForeignKey("ReceiverId")]
        public virtual ComUser Receiver { get; set; }

        [Column("COLLECTION_DATE")]
        public DateTime? CollectionDate { get; set; }

        [Column("STATUS_ID")]
        public long? StatusId { get; set; }

        [Include]
        [Association("Status", "StatusId", "StatusId", IsForeignKey = true)]
        public virtual LabStatus Status { get; set; }

        [Column("IS_ACTIVE")]
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        [Column("TEMPLATE_ID")]
        public long? TemplateId { get; set; }

        [Include]
        [Association("Template", "TemplateId", "TemplateId", IsForeignKey = true)]
        public virtual LabTemplate Template { get; set; }

        [Column("REASON_ID")]
        public long? ReasonId { get; set; }

        [Include]
        [Association("Reason", "ReasonId", "ReasonId", IsForeignKey = true)]
        public virtual LabReason Reason { get; set; }

        [Column("RECEIVED_DATE")]
        public DateTime? ReceivedDate { get; set; }

        [Include]
        [Association("Samples", "RequisitionId", "RequisitionId")]
        [ForeignKey("RequisitionId")]
        public ICollection<LabSample> Samples { get; set; }

        [Include]
        [Association("Attributes", "RequisitionId", "RequisitionId")]
        public ICollection<LabRequisitionAttribute> Attributes { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return LabNumber == null ? "New" : LabNumber.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

On my PC, this is the schema sql that is generated for that entity:

```
-- Table LAB_REQUISITION
CREATE TABLE LAB_REQUISITION ( 
  REQUISITION_ID NUMBER(18) NOT NULL,
  MATERIAL_ID NUMBER(18) NULL,
  LAB_NUMBER NUMBER(10) NULL,
  COLLECTOR_ID NUMBER(18) NULL,
  RECEIVER_ID NUMBER(18) NULL,
  COLLECTION_DATE TIMESTAMP(7) NULL,
  STATUS_ID NUMBER(18) NULL,
  IS_ACTIVE NUMBER(1) NOT NULL,
  TEMPLATE_ID NUMBER(18) NULL,
  REASON_ID NUMBER(18) NULL,
  RECEIVED_DATE TIMESTAMP(7) NULL,
  ROW_VERSION NUMBER(18,2) NULL,
  CREATED TIMESTAMP(7) NULL,
  CREATED_BY_ID NUMBER(18) NULL,
  LAST_UPDATED TIMESTAMP(7) NULL,
  LAST_UPDATED_BY_ID NUMBER(18) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (REQUISITION_ID)
)
/
```

On the server, this is the schema generated:

```
-- Table LAB_REQUISITION
CREATE TABLE LAB_REQUISITION ( 
  REQUISITION_ID NUMBER(18) NOT NULL,
  MATERIAL_ID NUMBER(18) NULL,
  LAB_NUMBER NUMBER(10) NULL,
  COLLECTOR_ID NUMBER(18) NULL,
  RECEIVER_ID NUMBER(18) NULL,
  COLLECTION_DATE TIMESTAMP(7) NULL,
  STATUS_ID NUMBER(18) NULL,
  IS_ACTIVE NUMBER(1) NOT NULL,
  TEMPLATE_ID NUMBER(18) NULL,
  REASON_ID NUMBER(18) NULL,
  RECEIVED_DATE TIMESTAMP(7) NULL,
  ROW_VERSION NUMBER(18,2) NULL,
  CREATED TIMESTAMP(7) NULL,
  CREATED_BY_ID NUMBER(18) NULL,
  LAST_UPDATED TIMESTAMP(7) NULL,
  LAST_UPDATED_BY_ID NUMBER(18) NULL,
  "Collector_UserId" NUMBER(18) NULL,
  "Receiver_UserId" NUMBER(18) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (REQUISITION_ID)
)
/
```

The **Collector_UserId** and **Receiver_UserId** columns are incorrect and they are causing the SQL select errors.

- I can't figure out why the model would generate correct SQL on my Dev PC but on the server it would generate the bogus extra columns.
- The app is exactly the same on Dev PC and the server except on the server I had to add the DbProviderFactories section to the app.config -- on my PC i'm guessing since Devart is installed that it is already registered.  Otherwise exactly the same.
- On my Dev PC the Devart libraries are being loaded from GAC whereas on the server they are loaded from the bin folder. As far as I can tell the versions are identical.

### Update 1 - Versions:

These are the versions and path for the EF and devart assemblies.

**SERVER**

Assembly:  EntityFramework
EntityFramework, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
file:///C:/apps/Cultivate.TestConsole/EntityFramework.DLL

Assembly:  Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity
Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity, Version=7.2.96.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701
file:///C:/apps/Cultivate.TestConsole/Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity.DLL

Assembly:  Devart.Data.Oracle
Devart.Data.Oracle, Version=7.2.96.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701
file:///C:/apps/Cultivate.TestConsole/Devart.Data.Oracle.DLL

Assembly:  Devart.Data
Devart.Data, Version=5.0.555.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701
file:///C:/apps/Cultivate.TestConsole/Devart.Data.DLL

**DEV PC**

Assembly:  EntityFramework
EntityFramework, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
file:///C:/dev/tfs/cul2/source/Cul2.Actions.Lab.TestConsole/bin/Debug/EntityFramework.DLL

Assembly:  Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity
Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity, Version=7.2.96.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701
file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity/v4.0_7.2.96.0__09af7300eec23701/Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity.dll

Assembly:  Devart.Data.Oracle
Devart.Data.Oracle, Version=7.2.96.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701
file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Devart.Data.Oracle/7.2.96.0__09af7300eec23701/Devart.Data.Oracle.dll

Assembly:  Devart.Data
Devart.Data, Version=5.0.555.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701
file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Devart.Data/5.0.555.0__09af7300eec23701/Devart.Data.dll

Comment: This situation is possible, if different versions of the EntityFramework.dll assembly are used. Please check, which version exactly is loaded on the server in fact.

Comment: I forgot to check EF but that too is the same, I updated the question with the versions of EF and devart assemblies.

Comment: I wonder if it matters that the Dev PC has VS 2012 and so it has .Net Framework 4.5 while the server would only have .Net 4.

Comment: Tried the app in a virtual using just 4.0 and it failed, tried using 4.5 and it also failed.  So it would seem the .Net framework is not causing this.